# Why do count(1), count(column) and count(*) have the same cost?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why do the three queries have the same cost? I'm thinking at least one should be faster. Otherwise, it would be alright to just use the keyword COUNT() instead of COUNT(parameter).

For example, here's a sample implementation of COUNT() that doesn't depend on the parameter:

```
while(!end of table){
    while(!end of record){
        read byte;
    }
    add 1 on a count register;
}
```

Query 1:

```
select column, COUNT(1) 
from table
group by column
```

Query 2:

```
select column, COUNT(column) 
from table
group by column
```

Query 3:

```
select column, COUNT(*) 
from table
group by column
```

Comment: run it in the query analyzer.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx

Comment: Count (x) will not take same cost if it has some null values.

Comment: @DanielA.White Clustered Index Scan -> Sort -> Stream Aggregate -> Compute Scalar -> Select

Comment: Why do you think that certain syntax exists only because there are performance differences? There are actual logical differences here - count(1) counts every row, count(*) counts every row, and both will use the most efficient index to do so. Count(column), on the other hand, has to worry about NULL values, since it will leave out any rows that aren't NULL - so it is not just about which one is faster, since the actual behavior is different.

Comment: @AaronBertrand One of the reasons is I'm wondering  why count() takes in parameters like it does. For example, count(column) can be replaced with select count() where column is not null. So, I'm wondering if there could be some other reason count(parameters) is written that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking, they don't have the same cost.  `count(1)` and `count(*)` should be optimized to be the same thing.  `count(<column>)` needs to compare the column value to `NULL`, incurring a slight overhead.

The reason they are basically the same is twofold.  First, the process of running a query consists of two phases:  compilation/optimization and execution.  The SQL compiler/optimizer is smart enough to know that `count(1)` and `count(*)` are the same thing (at least for most databases).

The second reason is because the time for a query is typically dominated by the I/O time for fetching records from a table -- particularly for simple queries.  So the overhead of comparing a column value to `NULL` is negligible compared to everything else the execution engine has to do.

Comment: Thanks. The statement that comparing the column value to NULL is negligible seems hard for me to believe yet. The comparison to NULL would be negligible if the SQL Server query analyzer uses something like a Big-O analysis. I'm estimating this type of analysis could neglect up to hundreds of seconds for a thousand second query.

Comment: @user3603463 Except it's not really comparing anything - it is actually quite simple for SQL Server to glance at a page and determine which rows to count using the NULL bitmap for that column.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So there is a NULL bitmap. I thought SQL Server would actually find nulls record by record.

Comment: What about `SUM(1)` vs `COUNT(*)` - maybe worth a mention as yet another alternative?